# How to install a package from a PPA and ignore the official one?

Tags: ppa, repository, aptitude, package-management

How do I tell aptitude to grab a package specifically from a PPA and ignore the one from official repository?

Comment: Can you use Synaptic? I believe you can do this in aptitude's ncurses interface, but I don't think you can from the commandline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to do it only once, just manual downloading and installing may be best way.

But if you'd like to update regulary, try to use APT pinning to force specific repo, you can find more on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#line-153

I've never used it for repo only to specify package version, so i'm not sure how to make it work this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can comment with # each official repo line, update aptitude, install, and uncomment these lines. Difficult, but works

Comment: this is a good solution however