# How do I customize the Ubuntu LiveCD?

Tags: 10.04, customization, custom-distributions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

I want to customize Ubuntu 10.04, below is the list of things which I want to do:

1. Install applications that I want.
2. Change OpenOffice version, Evolution and Firefox version.

How do I do that?

Comment: why not just make a default install and than install what you want with a post-install script? it's easier...

Comment: You can start here:http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd/49679#49679

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are pre-existing questions/answers on the site.

[Using a PPA to install a version of a program other than the version in the Softeware Centre](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49843/how-to-install-a-package-from-a-ppa-and-ignore-the-official-one)

[How to install software in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center)

Answer (score 0):

Your question has many answer but I think this is easier to do.

- make [post-install scripts](https://askubuntu.com/q/47404/10698)
- Then install the [Ubuntu version](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) of your choice.

If you don't like the software center (like me) you can simply install the programs via a terminal with the command `sudo apt-get install PackageName`

Like: `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

Then I simple suggest that you run your scripts. The scripts should simply set up ubuntu the way you want. Install any programs you want and/or set up the system with like; power management, system theme, user background etc.

Good luck and it's always easier to have post-install scripts if you would need to re-install Ubuntu or upgrade it.

Answer (score -1):

I just use remastersys.  It just works.
Go here for tips on how to use it http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/remastersys
Add deb http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/repository karmic/
to your sources
Yes, the karmic part is fine, as its for grub2 based ubuntu

Comment: Please ad more information! What do we have to do to use this "remastersys" ? *we can't google*

Comment: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/remastersys  add deb http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/repository karmic/ to your sources and install remastersys.

Comment: I don't want to read a comment to be able to use a answer! put it in your answer!