# How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, software-installation

The title says it all. I'd like to know how I can install software - an example is the Chromium web browser.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## For Unity on 11.10+

Step one: Open up the Software Center.

To do that, open the Dash and search for `Software` - you'll see something like the screenshot below:

[image: Searching the Dash]

Open the Software Center by clicking on it. Wait for it to load.

Now, search for the software you want to install - in this example, "Chromium Web Browser".

[image: Searching for Chromium]

Then, select the software and click the "More info" button.

From here you can view the version, the total amount of space it will take up once you've installed it, etc.

To install it, click the "Install" button on the right.

[image: Install button]

Once you've done that, you'll be asked to enter in your password - do that, then sit back and relax and Chromium will be installed.

You can change "chromium" to anything else that you need to get installed - Wunderlist, Geany, etc.

Answer (score 14):

### For systems Without Unity (using GNOME-Classic):

This is how you install a program via the Ubuntu software center.

- Start Ubuntu software center.

[image]

- navigate to the program you want to install. Either **search** for it, or navigate via the **Departments**.

[image]

- Then either hit **more info** or if you are certain you are correct press **install**

[image]

When you have read more about the program and feel it's the correct one, hit **install**.
Also notice if the program will **cost** you anything, most are free but some do have a price.

[image]