# How do I install software?

Tags: software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center)

I am new to ubuntu and i was wondering if anyone could show me a tutorial or actually show me how to install software, for example browsers or things like that. Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu.  Are you asking how to install software from source-code - or how to install software from the "software-center"?  Also please add the version of ubuntu you are using to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Open Ubuntu Software Center. By default, it's on the launcher at the left of your screen. Installing software is really easy. You just select the software you want from a catalog and click Install to install it.

You can install directly from the web as well. Have a look at this: http://apps.ubuntu.com, It's not as user friendly as the software center, but it certainly works. :)

Comment: Thank you, my second question is that i installed something from the software center, but i don't know where it went or how to open it >.>

Comment: Software becomes available in the dash. You can click the ubuntu button at the top of the launcher, on the left side, or you can press super+a. We call it super. You may call it the Windows key. You can drag applications from the dash to the launcher to make it more accessible, or you can right click the icon when the app is running, and select to "Keep in launcher".