# What can i do with ubuntu?

Tags: command-line

Well i have dual booted system , i have windows7 + ubuntu..

but on ubuntu i don't know what to do , what should i do with ubuntu like is there anything entertainment to do ?

like i don't have gonme desktop and i don't know how to ..

the system-prefenceses arent located on my desktop i don't know what should i do ?

tell me anything ..btw how can i install gnome?

thank you.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: The Question should instead be 'What cannot I do with Ubuntu?'

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This sort of discussion is a better fit for the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/66447/10698
Here's a question that will guide you on how to use the Ubuntu Software Center. Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to be nice and help you out here. When your on your Ubuntu partition log in and open Software Center. Its the shopping bag on the side panel. From there you can install almost every program available to Ubuntu/Linux. Just type your password when you go to install something (it will pop up with a window). It's that simple :D.