# remove third party software

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center)

I've just installed ubuntu 11.10 but having some problems 
1.can't able to view installed software 
2.can't able to install new software
3.can't able to remove third party software
so what can i do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The [software-center](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter) should help you in this task. To start this application manually, press **Alt-F2** and type "software center", or you can also execute the command `software-center` using the console.