# Can not install some programs from Web

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center)

Hey I install today and completely  new

I was wondering how do i install programs.
I used too use windows and I'm used to going on web and it installing.
but it doesn't seem to work on here Can i get some help please.

Comment: have you investigated the software center?  Can you add links to you question to programs you are trying to install?

Comment: [Read about the Software Center here](http://askubuntu.com/q/66447)

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu We have the Software Center For Installing New Softwares
[image]

and by the way windows software's not work in Ubuntu Unless u install " Wine " package (To Run Windows Software's in Ubuntu { You Can Google it "How to Run Windows Software's In Ubuntu"

**Note** : Windows Software's Are In .exe format ( example firefox.exe ) and Ubuntu Software's Are In .deb format ( example firefox.deb )

**Note** : For New User's Always Try To Install Software's From Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: Technically, `.deb` packages are like `.zip` archives containing executables. Windows use the `exe` extension for marking a file as executable where Ubuntu uses file permissions to control that. Under Windows, Firefox would get installed as `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe` while Ubuntu uses `/usr/bin/firefox` (note: no extension)

Answer (score 0):

Many programs You can install the same way like You did on Windows: just download and run installer (usually file: install.run or similar) or just simply run an executable file usually in Your applications bin folder.

For example Scilab app:

```
just download

find Scilab-X.Y.Z/bin/scilab and click it twice
```

And You have Scilab app running :]

But in general the best way is to Use software manager.
Regards