# How do I activate the Broadcom wireless driver?

Tags: wireless, drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install a graphics or wireless card driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-a-graphics-or-wireless-card-driver)

I have downloaded the drivers that are supposed to fix my wireless problem.  The problem is the instructions do not seem to fit the new GUI.

Here are the instructions:

From the GUI:
Package Manager (System>Administration>Synaptic Package Manager). Click the 
Reload button in the upper left corner of Synaptic to refresh your index then 
search for and reinstall the package named bcmwl-kernel-source.

With the new GUI, where do I go?  There is no 'System' any more.  Dash can't find 'Synaptic Package Manager'.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ubuntu Software Center instead of synaptic, synaptic does not come installed by default in Ubuntu anymore. You can still look for package names there.

As an option you can also install synaptics using this command in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

[image]

You will be able to use synaptic by opening the dash and looking for it.

Comment: I followed your instructions, installed Synaptic Package manager, installed the Broadcom-STA package, but it does not seem to have worked.  How do I connect my adapter to those drivers?