# Debian packages for Ubuntu

Tags: installation, debian, websites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center)

Some times it's difficult to install a software from tgz,bz2,... packages . Some times it doesn't response good results . Some times it makes persons nervous . This problem solved by using deb packages .

Can you recommend me a site for downloading debian package softwares ?

Thanks.

Comment: have you heard of apt-get ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to know the easy way to install packages.

For the most part you do not need to compile from tars.

You just install using a package manager e.g. Software Center or Synaptic.

Have a look at this: http://www.linuxnewbieguide.org/content/chapter-9-how-do-i-install-software-linux

Comment: Thanks for responding ,That's true , buts installing debian packages is very easy and simple .

Comment: @Mohammed: But that's exactly what Software Center and Synaptic do -- they install deb packages from a centralized repository! So normally, there shouldn't be really any need to download and install a deb file manually.

Comment: And even if you can, you shouldn't (Assuming you have the package in the repo). An important aspect of Linux is lost if you go downloading random stuff on the internet and installing it in superuser mode.

Comment: Internet speed in Ubuntu is very very low than windows.I download packages 9x faster than Ubuntu .There should be a safe software center on web , ha?

Comment: @Mohammad http://packages.ubuntu.com/