# How to install apps on virtualized Ubuntu system?

Tags: installation, virtualization

This question might seem to be basic and rudimentary, but I just have to ask because I'm not getting it.

I downloaded XAMPP and  Eclipse to my system and after starting Ubuntu through VMware I can't find the applications in my directory. Is this normal ? How can I find and  install the applications or any other software?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](http://askubuntu.com/q/66447/10698)

Comment: I disagree this is a duplicate of this one. That other question is more about 'how to use USC', while this one is 'what is the right way to get apps' - probably the OP does not know about USC and wants to install applications "the windows way", i.e. find an .exe installer and run it - so I expect answers that would explain what USC is, why it's cool, how to do in case application is not in repos, and maybe some note on alternative ways of installing apps in Ubuntu. ;-)

Comment: @rafalcieslak .. Exactly. I downloaded XAMPP and i was looking for a .exe to do a quick installation. But here i am no .exe file . I've only being around the Ubuntu platform for less than a day......

Comment: You might look at e.g (1) "Easily Install & Configure XAMPP/LAMPP with GUI in Ubuntu" - http://it-diary.com/tutorials/easily-install-configure-xampplampp-with-gui-in-ubuntu/ and (2)"How to install Eclipse" - http://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse

Answer (score 2):

To install software within a virtual machine it is easiest to use the tools Ubuntu installs there (assuming you set it up with Internet access). Here's a list from easiest to hardest:

First Option: **Ubuntu Software Center**

Located in Menu->Ubuntu Software Center.If you are using Unity, open the dash and type software,then the software center will appear.

[image: The windows of USC]

Then click on the search box at the top right to search for an application(eg if you type "Ge" -> gedit will show up).

Alternately, click on a category such as Developer Tools and search for the software you want to install.

When you find it,click on the "Install" button at the top right,(or "use source" if you just installed ubuntu), enter your password for verification and wait for the software to install.

---

Second Option: **Installation of .deb files**

Since all the apps at ubuntu software center are in fact .deb files,you can search for a .deb file at the internet,download it and then when you choose to open it choose "Open with Ubuntu Sofware Center"

---

Third Option: **Installation of source files (tar.gz,tar.gz2 etc)**

That is more like a terminal job rather than easy installation clicks.

1)First of all,after downloading the source file,unzip it with the archive manager and save the unzipped folder of the file somewhere(eg the Desktop)alternatively you can type the command:

```
$tar -zxvf program.tar.gz
$tar -zjvf program.tar.bz2
```

2) Run as root by typing `sudo -i` , then type your password.

3)Change to the directory of the folder(if you have the folder at the desktop type `cd /home/your_user_name/Desktop/your_file_name`

4)Type `./configure`

5)Type `make`

6)Type `make install`

Answer (score 1):

XAMPP is just a bundle of existing tools, all of which can be installed individually from the Ubuntu Software Center.  By using the version from the Ubuntu repositories, security upgrades and other updates will be taken care of for you, and you know they've been tested to work with the rest of your specific system.

From inside of your VM, the command-line install for the basic webserver with PHP, perl, and mysql installed:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 libapache2-mod-perl libapache2-mod-auth-mysql mysql-server mysql-client php5 php5-mysql perl
```

For the other packages that XAMPP installs that you may or may not need (pick and choose as needed):

```
sudo apt-get install webalizer proftpd php5-curl php5-gd php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-mhash php5-ming php5-sqlite
```

You would need to do some additional configuration of each, but you would need to do that with XAMPP as well.  I've left out some of the more oscure things that XAMPP seems to bundle - check http://packages.ubuntu.com to see if you can find them as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is kind of a hierarchy for installing:

1. Use a Package Manager to install automagically from a repository. That Package Manager might be Software Centre, Synaptic or something else.
2. Download a .deb. Install it by right clicking on the .deb and installing with Gdebi
3. As a last recourse unpack or compile from a .tar

Look particularly at "Installing Software in Ubuntu" - http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/installingsoftware

Basic Toolkit

1. Download the Linux Starter Pack - http://www.tuxradar.com/linuxstarterpack
2. Look at the UNOFFICIAL Ubuntu Guide - http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Oneiric
3. Look at Psychocats - http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu
4. Download the Ubuntu Pocket Guide and Reference - http://www.ubuntupocketguide.com/index_main.html
5. Download Ubuntu 11.10 Manual - http://ubuntu-manual.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem here could be that you downloaded the files to your system, **then** started the VM running Ubuntu.  A virtual machine doesn't get any access to the rest of your hard drive other than what you give it- A virtual machine runs on a virtual drive isolated from the rest of your system.

You'll need to make a shared directory that the VM can access and put the files there, or copy them over by some other means such as a USB stick.  You could have also downloaded and installed the programs directly into Ubuntu on the Virtual Machine.  Eclipse is available in the repositories, however there's little more required than downloading the archive and unzipping it.