# Why does apt-get fail to install the python-gasp package?

Tags: installation, package-management

when I try to install gasp in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS the following error occurs.

```
student@student-25:~$ sudo apt-get install python-gasp

[sudo] password for student: 

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package python-gasp
```

any help ,please?

Comment: Did you tried to install python-gasp from synaptic manager.

Comment: @tijybba he needs to enable Universe first.

Comment: Related (to unable to update issue in comments):  http://askubuntu.com/questions/154137/why-does-apt-get-give-me-an-unable-to-connect-error

Answer (score 2):

Your system is not using the "Universe" repositories.  You need to enable the Universe repositories to get `python-gasp`.

[This answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/148653/10616) will explain how to enable those repositories graphically.  Once you've enabled them and updated your system with apt-get, you should be able to find that package.

If you are on a command-line-only setup, then I will give you a set of commands to run here, courtesy of bodhi.zazen's answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/89100/10616).

(1) Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` with any editor with superuser powers (for command line, I recommend `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`, for graphical, `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`).

(2) Modify your `sources.list` file to look similar to this:

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main universe

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main universe
```

While this does not put the "Multiverse" repositories in (non-free software), you do not necessarily need Multiverse (if you want it, add "multiverse" to the end of each of the deb lines above.)  For whatever archive is there in your *current* sources.list, use that one instead of the us archives, I'm in the US so I have that in this.

(3) `sudo apt-get update` to update the repository information

(4) `sudo apt-get install python-gasp` should now work.

Comment: @ Bell -Alternately you can try from Update manager settings, Tick Mark the (Universe) end-name entry from the Ubuntu software Column, refresh and install it.

Comment: That can be done, but alternatively, search "Software Sources" in the dash, and use that tool, Update Manager just starts "Software Sources". Its all explained in the [first linked answer in my answer on this question you are reading](http://askubuntu.com/a/148653/10616)

Comment: I did as you told me,Lord of Time,but when I update it says:     W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: 

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: @ Lord of Time - Yes , now i learned to refer to links in answers before commenting them :D  Thanks Though.

Comment: @bell make sure to use your more local mirrors, you dont have to use the US mirrors. You may also want to check your network settings, since the US mirror might be blocked... which country are you in?  (also, see your other question about why apt won't update, its directly related to the problem you just described)

Comment: It is prob. easier to explain if you write the new kod in your post and ask to copy that and put that in a file named something like this: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-universe.list`.  Then noone needs to edit a file, which is usually easier.

Comment: @Anders this is the recommdned methodology, for the main repos its best to keep them bunched together.

Comment: @Lord of Time it is the most commonly used, but I haven't seen any recommendation aginst add in a file like this.
I think there are some reasons to not edit `sources.list` and instead add a file in the `sources.list.d` directory.  For one, it is muche easier to administrate.  And beginners do have less risk of messing things up.   If it doesn't work, just remove the file.  Which is better, as many forget to make a backup of the old one, or even recommend the beginner to make one before changing the file.
But, that is all a matter of opinions, and I accept that you have another view.

Comment: i tried today but it gives me z ff again ,Lord of Time.   W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http: 

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
I'm confused!

Comment: @bell [You have another question open about your internet problem with this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154137/why-does-apt-get-give-me-an-unable-to-connect-error) since you already asked why you cant get downloads.  The issue is your internet, not the repositories, I tested the method I outlined here, both graphically and command-line on 5 other systems yesterday using 5 different world-regional mirrors, and this worked (the package exists)

Answer (score -2):

By typing apt-get install you are looking for the package using synaptic package manager.Your output message clearly shows that the package you are looking for doesn't exist in the program.

You have to download the source file of the package and install it.

Download your package from [here](https://launchpad.net/gasp-core/+download)

[Information on how to install a tar.gz file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147807/how-to-install-applications-on-ubuntu/147912#147912)

Comment: Not true. It exists in universe.  i'm explaining how to turn on that repository now in a separate answer.  (proof of existence: [python-gasp on packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-gasp))

Comment: Wait a sec.What is the difference of downloading the source file and installing it instead of adding a new rep?I see no point why you believe my answer is not appropriate...:?

Comment: Building the latest source can break things, or have dependencies that do not exist in ubuntu.  Since this exists in the repositories, it is advisable to use that, as it has a higher likelihood of not causing dependency problems.  There's also a billion other reasons as to why you wouldnt want to build from source, such as easy uninstallation (which yuo dont get with building direct from source, because there's no package you can just uninstall)

Comment: Your opening statement is erroneous.  [Synaptic](http://wiki.debian.org/Synaptic) is a GTK+ front-end to [APT](http://wiki.debian.org/Apt). Typing `apt-get install` calls the `apt-get` executable form the APT tools with an argument of `install`