# Why does apt-get give me an "Unable to connect" error?

Tags: updates

After installing Ubuntu 12.04, I tried to update, but I got the following:

```
student@student-25:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423) precise InRelease
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423) precise/main TranslationIndex
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423) precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i38Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                 
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                               
  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:
```

Help?

Comment: Check your internet connection.

Comment: No internet connection or the server from where you are trying to install the package is unavailable.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/154122/why-does-apt-get-fail-to-install-the-python-gasp-package

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there will be a temporary server down too . I am suggesting you to change your server to Best server or update your system after sometime.

```
To change the server Open `Update Manager > Settings > Ubuntu Software > Download from:`
```

that option will hold the server option . choose a best server and try again .

Comment: I tried the main server but no help.it says  "Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]"

Comment: yeah sounds like temp server down .try again after sometime . P.S my ping can read the data from it .

Comment: I tried a lot of servers but the error while updating is still there.strangely in this morning sudo apt-get update told me as;"   student@student-25:~$ sudo apt-get update
       sudo: timestamp too far in the future: Jun 23 23:41:22 2012
[sudo] password for student:

Comment: @bell contact whoever manages your network it seems your internet firewalls are blocking everything.  If you're on a home network, try to DMZ your system in your router (temporarily)

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a good idea to change a server that isn't responding to one in the same general area. For example, I was using lug.bu.edu (Boston University) and it was giving me some problems. I changed it (in Synaptic) mirrors.mit.edu/ubuntu and all was smooth sailing. Bear in mind that you can almost always use the main server if a nearby mirror isn't working.