# How to install apps which is in downloads folder?

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a .tar.gz  (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

I have downloaded indicator-multiload-o.2.tar.gz in my downloads folder.Tell me how to install

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to install indicator-multiload you have done it wrong. You have downloaded the source code of the program, while you can use it to [install it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file), you need to compile it, and this can be non-trivial for someone without programming training.

To install software in Ubuntu you should always look first in the [Ubuntu Software Centre](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center).

It the program is not available in it, or you want a newer version you should look for [PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them).

If there is no PPA avaliable or you want to just download one file, look for a .deb file. You should be able to install it just with a double-click.

There are more ways to install programs in Ubuntu, but if you are a novice you should probably avoid them for now.

Answer (score 0):

Open the archive, and read the included README and/or INSTALL files. If there aren't any, there should be some other file which specifies how to install it.