# Software sources not showing in dash

Tags: software-center, unity-dash

I want to install spotify and therefor I need to find something called "Software sources".
It should be found in dash. But I can only find Software center. In software center I can find "Software sources" and it says installed. I tried to uninstall it and reinstall it.

I can't open it from the software center. And Dash doesn't find it. How can I find it? Totally new at this.

Comment: You can find _Software Sources_ in your system configuration (hackwrench & gadget icon on left panel). However, you should interact with them when you become a little bit more experienced. Software in Ubuntu is installed mostly through _Software Center_. Just enter keywords inside search field and choose software from proposed variants. Spend some time to reading about them and you will find what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center)

Comment: @Danatela The OP probably needs to enable a repository (be it partner, multiverse, etc.) before they can install the corresponding software in the Software Centre.

Comment: Are you running 13.04? "Software Sources" has been renamed "Software and Updates".

Answer (score 7):

In 13.04, it was renamed to "Software and Updates". It is the same application, just with a different name.

Screenshot below:
[image: Software & Updates in the Unity Dash]

Answer (score 1):

### Ubuntu 16.04 and later

Spotfy is a snap package in Ubuntu 16.04 and later. To install Spotify open the terminal and type;

```
sudo apt install snapd  
sudo snap install spotify
```

### Ubuntu 13.04-14.04

Open the Ubuntu Software Center and from the Ubuntu Software Center menu select *Edit* -> *Software Sources*. Or if you are using Ubuntu 13.04 or Ubuntu 13.10, search the Dash for *software* and click the *Software & Updates* icon.

---

To install spotify-client, the Debian/Ubuntu client for Spotify, open the terminal and follow the following steps:

1. Edit the sources.list file by adding the Spotify repository to it:

   ```
   sudo nano '/etc/apt/sources.list'
   ```

   Add this line to sources.list:

   ```
   deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
   ```

   Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the sources.list file. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.
2. Run the following command to add the Spotify public key:

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
   ```
3. Tell your system to pull down the latest list of software from each archive it knows about, including the Spotify repository you just added:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install Spotify:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install spotify-client
   ```

Comment: Is it `sudo apt-key adv` or `sudo apt-key add`?

Comment: @AnwarShah There does exist an `adv` option and the `v` key is far enough away from the `d` key not to be an accident. See [`apt-key`'s manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man8/apt-key.8.html)