# New to ubuntu can not find vlc on ubuntu search or install need some help here please

Tags: software-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu and it's an awesome system but i can't find vlc on the ubunut search or figure out how to install any software like flash player etc can anyone help out please will be greatly appreciated

Comment: sudo apt-get install vlc

Comment: See this question which teaches you how to install software: http://askubuntu.com/q/66447/176889

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest version of vlc in Ubuntu via PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Through the **Ubuntu Software Center**, you can download and install any software in Ubuntu.
Download Ubuntu software center from [here](https://launchpad.net/software-center).

Comment: Why in the world would you need to download the Ubuntu Software Center **on Ubuntu**?!?

Comment: If you use a derivative that hasn't Software Center installed by default, you may want to install it. But that was not stated in the question. Installing a PPA was also not part of the question and isn't necessary.

Comment: While some Ubuntu derivatives (including some official derivatives) don't include the Software Center by default, there's nothing on `software-center`'s [Launchpad source package page](https://launchpad.net/software-center) that provides a reasonable way for most people to install it. A properly functioning, Internet-connected Ubuntu system without the Software Center can be outfitted with the Software Center simply by running `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install software-center`. (For Lubuntu, users may prefer `lubuntu-software-center`, which may already be installed.)

Answer (score 0):

press window or super button.type ubuntu software centre and open it..its like a play store you have in android.search for software(like vlc or xbmc) u want and install it...

Answer (score 0):

[Usage of Software Center](https://askubuntu.com/q/66447/176889) should be self-explanatory, but you can also use the web interface:

- [VLC](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc/) in Software Center
- [Adobe Flash plugin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/flashplugin-installer/) in Software Center
- [Ubuntu restricted extras](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/) in Software Center