# Is there a place or software in ubuntu like controol panel add/remove programs

Tags: package-management, uninstall, gui, installed-programs

is there a software or add/remove programs like windows that keeps a list of all installed used programs list on ubuntu.
gui is prefered here.

so that its easy.
we do not have to use terminal.

Comment: I think you are talking about Ubuntu software centre and download synaptic package manager..

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center - once software is installed there will be a remove button.

Answer (score 2):

The analogue to Add/Remove porgrams in Ubuntu is USC - Ubuntu software center, which You can start from Your "main Ubuntu" menu. Which is dash in 12.04 and Gnome panel in previous versions. Also in previous versions there was Synaptic package manager, which was something like install/remove utilities and libraries from windows.

Also there is apt (Advanced Package ... something :p) which is very advanced command-line tool for installing applications and other software. (In previous versions also aptitude and dpkg are present)

So if You need to uninstall some package or app, that You know by name, try:

sudo apt-get remove packagename
or try to find it in Ubuntu Software Center, and click uninstall.

You can also install Synaptic pagckage manager to list all the packages present on your system and you can modify them.

Answer (score 1):

It's called Ubuntu Software Center. You can list installed applications, search for available applications, install, uninstall etc. I'm on XUbuntu so can't direct you how to open i from the GUI, but you can start it from the terminal using 'software-center'