# How to Run Packet tracer

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded packet tracer which  was a zip file, and after extracting it, i am not sure how to run it since when i open the folder there aren't any icons (I have been used to windows) and to make me a little more lost, upon opening the folder it has an "install script".  I added the liberty of sharing this through Google drive  so you can replicate and better understand my problem. Use VM wear with it or just click the download arrow at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwNyCfESFvvUMWJoVVB1Qm9nSkk/view
Thanks for your time.!

Comment: As a general rule, don't download random zips of junk from the internet and try to run it.  Use the software center to install software.  The program you are looking for is called wireshark.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center)

Comment: Cisco has a network simulator named Cisco Packet Tracer and i Downloaded though netacad.com / it has an ubuntu version which i recently cannot get to work which is why i posed a download link  . Jos (who cmt below) seamed to work however it only lets me open it through gedit that displays #!/bin/bash echo Starting Packet Tracer 6.2 PTDIR=/opt/pt export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PTDIR/lib pushd $PTDIR/bin > /dev/null ./PacketTracer6 "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1 popd > /dev/null and idon't know what it means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unzip the file into a local directory. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and `cd` to the directory. Find the install script and enter `chmod +x install` followed by `sudo ./install`. That should work.

A little explanation: The `chmod` makes your script executable (which it isn't by default, for security reasons). The install script itself should be run with `sudo` because ordinary users can not modify system directories.

Comment: Please explain why the answer was downvoted?

Comment: That is executable code, a script that you can run, so run it. If you get "Starting Packet Tracer 6.2" and no error messages, it is running.

Comment: It only lets me open it in gedit and displays #!/bin/bash echo Starting Packet Tracer 6.2 PTDIR=/opt/pt export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PTDIR/lib pushd $PTDIR/bin > /dev/null ./PacketTracer6 "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1 popd > /dev/null   I wish i can explain this better but on windows when something is installed it creates an icon /.executable file that all i need to do is double click on it and then it opens up but here it give's me the above display in a gedit. I posted a download link so that someone can try themselves with download arrow. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwNyCfESFvvUMWJoVVB1Qm9nSkk/view

Comment: Open a terminal (as I said before), cd to the directory and enter the name of the file as a command. You should probably put `sudo` in front of it, in order to run as root, and `./` to indicate that the script file is in the current directory.

Comment: Hey I guess it works however the terminal reads Starting Packet Tracer 6.2 But doesn't open up so i guess netacad.com has bad start up code or something . umm as an alternative can i use wine in the software center and then use the windows version?

Comment: See if the software you want to run is mentioned in the database at [winehq.org](http://winehq.org). If it isn't, you can't. Anyway that is a completely different question. If my answer has been useful, please click the check mark next to it.

Comment: i cant tell if it is or not because nothing new comes up on my task bar even though the terminal says "Starting Packet Tracer 6.2" and no error message do not show up.

Comment: Use the command `ps -ef|less` to see if there is actually something running.

Comment: I rebooted my computer and it now shows up as a shortcut my desktop and thanks to Jos knowledge, and steps to do, the problem is no more with full functionality.  Thanks.