# How to install GMT in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

I want to install [GMT](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/) in my laptop 64 bit with ubuntu 14.04LTS, could you give me more detail idea. How to install GMT ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center) – search for `gmt` (duh…)

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install gmt
```