# How to install Octave in Ubuntu 14.04 using terminal

Tags: apt, dependencies, packaging, octave

`sudo apt-get build-dep octave` is not working. 
The error message is

```
E: Build-Depends dependency for octave cannot be satisfied because the package automake cannot be found
```

I have modified the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with `deb` replaced by `deb-src`. Even when I try `sudo apt-get install octave`, an error is displayed that the package is not located.

Edit: I have added deb-src lines into sources.list file(not replaced deb this time) and then sudo apt-get update. Now when  I try to build the dependency I am getting this error :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: libgraphicsmagick++1-dev : Depends: libgraphicsmagick1-dev but it is not going to be installed.  
E: Build-dependencies for octave could not be satisfied.
```

Comment: Why would you *replace* `deb` with `deb-src`? Undo that and **add** `deb-src` lines instead.

Comment: @muru Ok I did that. Now I'm getting this error: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgraphicsmagick++1-dev : Depends: libgraphicsmagick1-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for octave could not be satisfied.

Comment: Edit your question if you have new information to add.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center)

Answer (score 1):

You can install Octave latest by using below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave

apt-get build-dep octave
```

Or

Adding a line to your */etc/apt/sources.list*

**amd64:** http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libgraphicsmagick3/filelist

**i386:** http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/libgraphicsmagick3/download

Or

You can Download and compile octave:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep octave
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-4.0.0.tar.gz
tar xf octave-4.0.0.tar.gz
cd octave-4.0.0/
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

Comment: I am getting an error while using `sudo apt-get build-dep octave`                     **The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgraphicsmagick++1-dev : Depends: libgraphicsmagick1-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for octave could not be satisfied**

Comment: Give a try to Download Octave and compile it ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-4.0.0.tar.gz

Comment: Octave is working without doing **sudo apt-get build-dep octave** . What is the need of this step then?