# Brand new user with Ubuntu and I need help with Firefox

Tags: firefox

I am very new to Ubuntu. Basically, the only way I can open firefox is by using the terminal and typing `~/firefox/firefox`. I can't find firefox when I search for it. All I want is to have firefox icon on my desktop so I don't have to use the terminal every time.

Comment: Also, I did some stuff with downloading linux 64 bit from the firefox website. I don't know what the heck I did with it though? Like I don't think I did anything? Like, did I have to extract anything....?

Answer (score 1):

please use [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center) to install software in ubuntu and avoid downloading and extracting software from external sites!

using the software center will guarantee that not just the operating system, but the whole system (with installed applications) will be up to date. - and by the way you can be sure that every application from the software center is checked, tested and won't harm your system...

**concerning your "problem":** after using the software center, the desired software will appear automatically in your menu...! **;-)**

Comment: after you installed firefox via the software center an everything works like expected you can/should clean up your system by removing the sideloaded firefox by opening a terminal and typing `rm -r ~/firefox/`.