# How do I install GnuPG 2.0?

Tags: software-installation, thunderbird, gnupg, enigmail

In Ubuntu 15.10 when using Mozilla Thunderbird with Enigmail I get the following warning (in Swedish):

> Du använder GnuPG version 1.4.18, vilken inte längre stöds. Enigmail
>   kräver GnuPG version 2.0.7 eller senare. Vänligen uppgradera din
>   installation av GnuPG annars fungerar inte Enigmail.

As I understand it my version of GnuPG is to old and I need to upgrade. However, I can't figure out how to do that.

At Enigmail FAQ I read that:

> you install GnuPG 2.0 via the regular package management system of
>   your distribution (e.g. apt, yum, yast). On many distributions the
>   package is called "gnupg2" or "gpg2"".

But I'm only a normal user, and I don't understand what that means and what I'm suppose to do.

I would be very happy for some help. For example some kind of very basic step by step ”How to” guide.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

On Ubuntu, GnuPG 2.0 is available for all supported releases under the package name [gnupg2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnupg2) (and they are all > 2.0.7). To install it, open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnupg2
```

Or see [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/q/66447/158442)

Comment: It should be noted that this *does not* install the `gpg` binary as that is _still_ version 1. You will have to `sudo apt-get remove gnupg` then `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gpg2 /usr/bin/gpg`

Comment: Alternatively you might want to keep `gpg` available in case you run into any problems, so you can always just call `gpg2` to use the new version.

Comment: At least for Ubuntu 18.04, now, and for me: (1) The `gnupg2` package wasn't available, (2) the command in the answer reported `However the following packages replace it: gpgv gpgsm gnupg-l10n gnupg dirmngr`, and (3) `sudo apt-get install gpgv gpgsm gnupg-l10n gnupg dirmngr` reported that all those packages were already current. Perhaps they came with my Ubuntu image. Hope it helps ...

Comment: @BaldEagle yep, in 18.04 the `gnupg` package is GnuPG 2, and `gnupg2` is a dummy package available in universe.

Comment: The version in the Ubuntu repos is 2.1.11, way behind the [current 2.2.8](https://www.gnupg.org/download/) release. This is annoying because [signing commits on GitHub requires v2.1.17](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-gpg-key/) or later.