# How to solve gpg: invalid option "--full-generate-key"?

Tags: 16.04, gnupg

I want to sign my GitHub commits with GnuPG. So I'm trying to generate a GPG key as instructed in this [article](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-gpg-key/).

But the problem is when I run this command on the terminal:

```
gpg --full-generate-key
```

I get the error:

```
gpg: invalid option "--full-generate-key"
```

I've also tried `gpg2 --full-generate-key` and still get the same error.

I've followed the instructions on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/748059/545800) to instal gpg. The installation succeeds, but the error remains. Is there any other installation step I'm missing? Or maybe a different option other than `--full-generate-key` to generate a GPG key?

Comment: use `gpg   --full-gen-key`

Comment: @ptetteh227 Thank you very much! It worked :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [the GnuPG documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/OpenPGP-Key-Management.html):

> `--full-generate-key`
>   `--full-gen-key`
>   Generate a new key pair with dialogs for all options. This is an
>   extended version of `--generate-key`.

`--full-generate-key` seems to be a new synonym, added in GnuPG 2.2. The [manpage for Ubuntu 18.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gpg2.1.html) mentions it, but not older manpages, which only list `--full-gen-key`. Note that `--full-gen-key` itself is a rename of the `--gen-key` option in [GnuPG 2.1.0 (2014)](https://www.gnupg.org/download/release_notes.html#gnupg-2.1.0), so you have to use the older option name with Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 9):

Facing the same issue. Here is my output

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gpg --full-generate-key
gpg: Invalid option "--full-generate-key"
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gpg --full-gen-key
gpg: Invalid option "--full-gen-key"
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gpg --generate-key
gpg: Invalid option "--generate-key"
```

The following command worked,

```
gpg --gen-key
```