# How do I install Ekiga?

Tags: 18.04, ekiga

How do I install Ekiga on Ubuntu 18.04?

The instructions seem to assume that you already have the software installed.

http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Manual#Getting_started_.28first_time_Assistant.29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and above (Updated)

Ekiga has been removed from the Ubuntu repositories for 20.04 and higher. As far as I can tell it was last updated in 2013. It is not maintained and updated anymore. Trying to use an unsupported version of software can be a security risk.

There are a few alternates I know about.

- [Empathy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Empathy)
- [Jami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jami_(software))
- [Twinkle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twinkle_(software))

All these software are available in the Ubuntu universe repositories.  Any of these can be installed in Ubuntu using the same methods described for Ekiga below.

**Note:** Jami is also available in a snap package. So, you will see two Jami entries if you search the Ubuntu Software Store.

A more comprehensive list of VoIP software for various platforms is available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_VoIP_software)

## For Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and below

### Use the Ubuntu Software Store

This is the way to install most software in Ubuntu. The icon looks like:

[image]

Press this icon and look for the search icon . Then search for `ekiga`

[image]

Select the **Ekiga Softphone** from the list.

Then press the install button:

[image]

Enter your password when asked.

That's how you install ekiga.

See [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center) for more details.

### Alternately use the command line

You don't have to use the command line instructions. It is just easier to write for me.

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo apt install ekiga
```

When you type your password nothing will happen, the cursor will not move and you will not see any ****. This is normal.

See [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu) for more detailed and general answers.

Hope this helps

Comment: Not works in ubuntu 20

Comment: @delive Ekiga is not available in Ubuntu 20.04 or higher. I have updated the answer.