# Problem in making customized Kubuntu LiveCD

Tags: kubuntu, live-cd

I have planned to make a customized "Kubuntu" 14.04 LiveCD. For that, I tried using Ubuntu Customization Kit. Several attempts were made and built many custom kubuntu iso files but none of them were in a working state. Process to make the custom iso was successful  and no errors occured in build process and also, the writing of iso was performed correctly to USB.

When booted with USB, I couldn't use it as a LiveUSB. So to track the actual fault, I installed it directly to Hard Drive. However it installed. But I couldn't login into the administrator account after installing that custom iso in my system. Only Guest was allowed to be accessed.

All the iso's created showed the same behaviour of being stuck, and hence I reinstalled back the Kubuntu again, that was available in the official website.

When searched in the internet, I came to know that custom KDE(kubuntu) iso made with Ubuntu Customization Kit will have some glitches, as UCK was excellent in handling GNOME, LXDE whereas it is not good in handling KDE.

Then googled out for other alternatives. I found Remastersys, Relinux, and Ubuntu Builder. Remastersys is discontinued and supports making custom LiveCD's upto Saucy Salamander. Ubuntu Builder is also a discontinued project. I cannot create custom iso using Relinux as it simply loops indefinitely i.e from start to end of config and goes back to starting of config.

### Reason for creation of Custom ISO:

I needed a backup of installed programs Cheese, GIMP, VLC, g++, build-essential, synaptic, XAMPP(installed manually from ApacheFriends) so that whenever I need a reinstallation, if installed with custom iso, I need not install again and again.

#### Links referred regarding this problem:

[How to customize Ubuntu Live CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65400/how-do-i-customize-the-ubuntu-livecd)

P.S. Is there any special software for KDE for making custom iso?

Comment: Although Remastersys is no longer being developed, it is still available for [download](http://www.remastersys.com/downloads/) and works with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @RohithMadhavan Sir, The point is I am using kubuntu and since kubuntu comprises of different config and dependencies compared to gnome, lxde or xfce, I am unsure it will work or not. Anyway let me try and report if it works

Comment: I created the iso image again now with relinux but when testes with virtualbox, I receive the following error message buring boot time of LiveCD:

"**call to lnusertemp failed(temporary directories full?). Check your installation**"
The same error was received when previous livecd's were created using Ubuntu Customization kit

Comment: @RohithMadhavan Sir, that didn't work too. Alright, since my aim is to have a backup of the installed software, is there any alternative way other than these custom iso's. Tried keryx too, but failed

Comment: You can copy the `deb` files in `/var/cache/apt/archives` and install them later using either the software center or `dpkg`.

Comment: @RohithMadhavan Sir, there is a problem again. Even though I have these .deb files, they however require internet connection for software installation, right?
I just want to have backup of installed software, just like an installer file for windows

Comment: @RohithMadhavan and Thanks for your hands-on support sir for testing Remastersyss with Kubuntu :)

Comment: The `deb` files do not need an internet connection to be installed. You can think of it as similar to `exe` files on Windows.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~cubic-wizard is the tool to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Finally made my custom kubuntu iso with the same Ubuntu Customization Kit, but this time I did it with help of VirtualBox.

1. First installed VirtualBox.
2. Then inside it, I installed a fresh copy of Kubuntu. Inside that, I installed Ubuntu Customization Kit. Then copied Kubuntu iso file, selected and configured it for my needs with Ubuntu Customization Kit.

I tested it and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

As your aim is just to have a total system backup, just use [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org) to make a clone ("image") of your system partition(s): 2 minutes of work, 30 minutes of waiting (depending on the size and speed of your computer)

Even the set-up is easy:

- Hook up an external USB HD
- Boot the CloneZilla CD
- [Clone partition using image](http://clonezilla.org/screenshots/?in_path=/00_Clonezilla) (take the MBR too!)

Done!

If your `/home` is *not on a separate partition* drop a note @Fabby